# How to see brew installed java with java -version command?

Tags: java, bash, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I have installed java open jdk latest version with homebrew with the following command:

```
brew install openjdk
```

I try to to check installed versions with the command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Nothing showing.

And the command `java -version` also showing :

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install
```

Where is my java ?  How can I see installed version and use it and see it with `java -version` command

Comment: try `ls /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk`

Answer (score 7):

I recommend installing the JDK cask `temurin` instead:

```
brew uninstall openjdk
brew install temurin
```

Otherwise, you must symlink the `openjdk` formula into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`:

```
sudo ln -sfn $(brew --prefix openjdk)/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Comment: Why would you not just sym link it?

Comment: Less steps (and therefore less maintenance)

Comment: However, I recommend symlinking if you already use `openjdk` (e.g. as a dependency of another formula)